# VBA *For Each Cell Loop* IF (Value in Column 1) = x AND IF (Equivalent Value In Column 2) >7 THEN

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am having an issue with VBA that I can't seem to find an answer to online. I only started teaching myself a couple of weeks ago so apologies if this is a fairly simple answer...

I am trying to write a macro where the entire row is un-coloured (Is that a word??) based on a value in column E and the equivalent value in column AN (same row). What I have so far is:

```
For Each cell In Sheets(5).Range("E9:E" & LastRow)

If (cell.Value = "BA" Or cell.Value = "NH" Or cell.Value = "AD") Then
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 35) > 7 Then
          cell.EntireRow.Interior.color = xlNone
End If
Next cell
```

The only problem is, when I try to run it gives the 'Compile error: Next without For' error message.

?? Am I missing something... there is a 'For'...

If I remove the below line then the code runs,

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 35) > 7 Then
```

but it's not the output i require as all of the BA, NH & AD values in column A have their entire row un-coloured regardless of whether they are >7 or <7.

Is the error caused by the IF-THEN-IF statement?

Comment: Close the nested if. There should be another `End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another issue besides not closing the `If` with `End If`.

- You are looping on `Cell` with `For Each Cell In Sheets(5).Range("E9:E" & LastRow)`
- Then you are testing to see if `Cell.Value = "BA" or` ...etc
- **However**, afterwards you are checking `If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 35) > 7 Then`, I think `ActiveCell` meant to be `Cell` as well.

One last thing, instead of using multiple `Or`, you can use `Select Case`.

**Code**

```
For Each Cell In Sheets(5).Range("E9:E" & LastRow)
    Select Case Cell.Value
        Case "BA", "NJ", "AD"
            If Cell.Offset(0, 35) > 7 Then
                Cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If

    End Select
Next cell
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
For Each cell In Sheets(5).Range("E9:E" & LastRow)

If (cell.Value = "BA" Or cell.Value = "NH" Or cell.Value = "AD") Then
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 35) > 7 Then
          cell.EntireRow.Interior.color = xlNone
    End If // You are missing this
End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()`:

```
    With Sheets(5)
        With .Range("E8", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 36)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("BA", "NJ", "AD"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:=">7"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
```